# Make TypeScript compiled files readonly

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, filesystems

There's [a suggestion on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41357) to make `tsc` mark compiled files readonly and it's deemed not feasible and it won't ever be a feature. As an absent-minded person who has modified compiled file instead of the source file many times, what are my options?

Unfortunately my project structure is not very good (but I cannot change for existing projects), where compiled `.js` files stays at the same folder as the `.ts` files:

```
|-- file.ts
|-- file.js
|-- another.ts
|-- another.js
|-- folder
    |-- file.ts
    |-- file.js
|-- non-typescript.js <-- not read-only
```

- In the above issue, someone suggests using different color for `.js` file vs `.ts` files, however my projects do have Javascript files (i.e. not compiled by TypeScript). This should not help much.
- VS Code has a readonly feature but then again if I have editable JS files among the generated, I cannot use it.

I am open to any IDE/environment build tools (WebPack, Rollup etc) though admittedly I have limited experience with them. If it's relevant, most of them are Chrome extensions or static web pages and we do not currently pack them, just compile and use the `.js` files.

Comment: Start generating checksums for the JavaScript files and check the sums in your run script. Or you know, specify an output directory so that the JS files are generated in a completely different folder from your TS files.

Comment: @kelsny yes I already did that for newer projects (separated output files). Unfortunately I inherited not a small amount of legacy projects that I cannot really change. How does JS checksum work?

Comment: Have your IDE ignore the build target directories?

Comment: @Pointy as stated in my question, the build "target folders" are the same folders as the source files.

Comment: Well that's pretty darn weird.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not compile js files next to ts files. Make your tsconfig `outDir` `dist/` , and use it.
2. Enable source maps. Then trying to open the file in devtools may open the source ts file